# Read files from repo on Github pages

Tags: angular, typescript, github-pages

I have a project where I need to be able to read text files that are on the assets folder of my repo.

I've never used Github Pages before and don't have much experience working with hosting services, for the deployment and hosting of this project I've followed this guide: https://angular.io/guide/deployment and It's worked, no problem.

When working on this project locally I was fetching the files like so:
`fetch('/assets/texts/instrucciones.txt')`

And I guess thats where the problem could be, does it make sense or could it be something else

Comment: Github pages only reads pure HTML, CSS, Javascript, I have same problem, and I never use it for my React app, I would suggest you to use Heroku or Netlify

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into them